# Split a date field output into two spans

Tags: 7, datetime

I have a Date field on a content type. I'm trying to render it so that just the Month and Day are visible, but I need each in a separate .

I think the most appropriate place to do this is in the preprocess function for the node theme function. Within that function, here's the date field on the node object:

[image]

**What is the appropriate way to convert this to something I can run a custom date formatter on, so I can get the month and the day separately?**

This is my current approach:

```
$date_field = $node->field_event_date_time[$node->language][0];
$date_object = new DateObject($date_field['value'], new DateTimeZone($date_field['timezone_db']));

$variables['event_month'] = date_format_date($date_object, 'custom', 'M');
$variables['event_day'] = date_format_date($date_object, 'custom', 'j');
```

But it does seem a bit messy, and I've noticed is that the field *won't always* have the language array key, so that complicates it a bit further.

Comment: I think u cn use php explode function

Comment: Wrap the node in an Entity metadata wrapper to get to the date field, or use field_get_items.

Answer (score 0):

If your current approach works, consider sticking with it.  Use field_get_items() to get past the "field won't always have the language" problem.

To answer the original question, at admin/config/regional/date-time you'll find a tab to create a new format.  You can somewhat laboriously create a format based on something like:

```
<\s\p\a\n \c\l\a\s\s="\f\o\o">l F j</\s\p\a\n> - <\s\p\a\n \c\l\a\s\s="\b\a\r">g:i a</\s\p\a\n>
```

All the backslashes may not be necessary, but you have to backslash escape any character that is a special date code.

Then edit a type or make a new one that uses your format with the markup built in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **theme hooks** to override the format of a specific date format as follows:

```
/**
 * Override theme_date_display_single().
 *
 * @param $variables
 *   An array of variables to pass to the theme template.
 */
function theme_date_display_single($variables) {
  if($variables['dates']['format'] == "d M Y"){
    // In this case i keep only start date. For keep end date use value2.
    $date = $variables['dates']['value']['formatted_iso'];
    $timezone = $variables['timezone'];
    $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
    // Set my vars
    $day = format_date(strtotime($date), 'custom', 'd');
    $month = format_date(strtotime($date), 'custom', 'M');
    $year = format_date(strtotime($date), 'custom', 'Y');

    // Wrap the result with the attributes.
    return '<span class="date-display-single"' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . '<span class="d">' . $day . '</span>' . '<span class="M">' . $month . '</span>' . '<span class="Y">' . $year . '</span>' . $timezone . '</span>';
  }
}
```

This solution has been posted here: https://www.drupal.org/node/423870#comment-9871591